# Why on splitting table to new page page padding is changed?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Why on splitting table to new page page padding/margins is/are changed? 
See what I mean: 
[image: Table]

Code:

```
//Some logic to get data. 
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(cols);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL);

    Phrase headerText = new Phrase(header);
    headerText.setFont(FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD,14.6f));

    PdfPCell headerRow = new PdfPCell(headerText);
    headerRow.setColspan(7);
    headerRow.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    headerRow.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    headerRow.setPadding(5);

    table.addCell(headerRow);

    Set<Integer> keys = data.keySet();

    double sum = 0;
    for (Integer key : keys) {
     //There data is added in table...
    }

    //generate pdf
    Document document = new Document();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,byteArrayOutputStream);
    document.open();
    document.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
    document.add(table);
    document.add(p);
    document.add(paragraph);
    document.addCreationDate();
    document.addTitle("Tenant activity");

    document.close();

    logger.debug("Pdf generated");
    File f = new File("activity.pdf");
    logger.debug("File path: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
```

How can I set **padding for page** / **margin for table**  same as on first page, to each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong order:

```
document.open();
document.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
```

This is the right order:

```
document.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
document.open();
```

When you open the document, or when you invoke `document.newPage()`, the next page is initialized, and you can't change page properties such as size or margins of that page.

So if you change the page size or margins, those changes will only be valid on the *next* page, not on the *current* page.

Why is this? Well, this is PDF, everything is page based, and once a page has been initialized, you'd get some really weird side-effects if you change those properties while adding content.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for answer.